# View controller changing tab bar icon and action

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitabbar

I'm trying to control the tab bar images with my view controller class. I would like to click a button and have the tab bar icon change. Snapchat currently does this when sending a snap.

Comment: Go to tabbarcontroller in storyboard and set the bartintColor

Comment: Snapchat doesnt have a tabbar :/

Comment: This is completely different. I don't want to change the color. i want to change the image of the tab by clicking on a button.

Comment: What code have you written to do this? Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [Ask]

Comment: Snapchat has a tab bar. They have 3 tabs in the bottom . When you send a snapchat, the camera tab turns purple.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too late, but for those passing by, i found an easier way to do this as i was looking.

For ease, use a Base class:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
func changeTabIcon(tab:Int){
       if let tabItems = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items {
       switch tab {
       case 0:
            tabItems[tab].selectedImage = UIImage(named: "house_fill")
       case 1:
           tabItems[tab].selectedImage = UIImage(named: "folder_fill")
       case 2: 
           tabItems[tab].selectedImage = UIImage(named: "business")
       case 3:
           tabItems[tab].selectedImage = UIImage(named: "cloud_fill")
       default:
           var _ = "something wrong"
       }
   }
   }
```

Then in all or the ViewControllers whose icons you want to change on click, call the method above this way:

```
class FirstViewController: BaseViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    changeTabIcon(tab: 0)
  }
}
```

And in the SecondViewController and so on:

```
class SecondViewController: BaseViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       changeTabIcon(tab: 1)
   }
  }
```

If you're not changing an icon when loading a ViewController, then just call

> changeTabIcon()

in your button action etc

Answer (score 0):

you could try executing this code on a button click:

```
viewControllerToChange.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "your_image_name")
```

**EXAMPLE**

lets say you have a tab bar with 3 View Controllers. we will call them `ViewController1`, `ViewController2`, & `ViewController3`

You want to change the tab bar icon (image) for `ViewController3` inside of `ViewController1` with a button click. In `ViewController1` you could have an `IBAction` to handle a button click and change the tab bar icon in `ViewController3` like so:

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {

    if let viewController3 = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[2] {

        viewController3.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "your_image_name")

    }
}
```

if you want to change the tab bar image within the same view controller you could simple put `self.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "your_image_name")` in your button click.

**NOTE**

`tabBarItem.image` **IS NOT** the same as `tabBarItem.selectedImage`. You will have to set the selectedImage if you want a different image when the tab is selected.